# Dialog not respecting MATCH_PARENT

Tags: android, android-layout

I intend to display a `Dialog` with a custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/lef_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/lef_margin"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgsocialauthclose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:background="@drawable/closexml" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Now, if I I set this layout to the dialog through, `Dialog.setContentView()`, I get something like below(*please note that the concerned Dialog is the thine white box with a cross button in the middle and the not the one with all the social media options in the background*):

[image]

Now, if I were to write this additional line in addition to the setContentView() call, I get a Dialog that extends to cover parent view:

```
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

If you observer the layout, you would notice that the MATCH_PARENT constraint has already been declared. Then, why do I need to do this additional line or,

Why doesn't the Dialog respect the MATCH_PARENT constraint properly by default?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this once for a dialog fragment by adding this to `onCreateDialog`.  This will make your dialog full screen. Then you can define margin/padding with transparent background to shape your dialog in any way you want.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity() ,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_NoActionBar);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

then to show the dialog just use

```
MyDialogFragment fragment = new MyDialogFragment();
fragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "addPlaylistDialog");
```